# Ansible - apply variable in SQL query

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
  - name: " username"
    prompt: "What is merchant name?"
    private: no
    register: reg_name
  - name: "password"
    prompt:  "Enter password"
    private: yes
    encrypt: "sha256_crypt"
    confirm: yes
    salt_size: 16
    register: s
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: password
      register: s
    - debug: var=s

- name: update db
      shell : echo -n "insert into database (id, createdDate, updatedDate, username, sharedSecretHash) values (7, strftime('%s', 'now'), strftime('%s', 'now'), "{{ reg_name.stdout }}", "{{ s.stdout }}");" | sqlite3 /tmp/test.db


FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'reg_name' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/prompt.yml': line 33, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: update db\n      ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'merchantname' is undefined"}
fatal: [10.1.1.1: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'reg_ name' is undefined\n\The error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/prompt.yml': line 33, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: update db\n      ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'merchantname' is undefined"}
```

I registered variables with reg_name.stdout for username and s.stdout for password  and trying to apply it in sql query, it throws error - var undefined. Please suggest.

Comment: You nested the quotation marks. I'm not sure how Ansible expands it. I can't see line 33 in your code (error appears to have been in ... line 33, column 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vars_prompt the content is stored in a variable with the same name (in this case, username and password). There is no need to use the attribute register. Actually, it is being ignored by ansible.

This Playbook has worked for me:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
  - name: " username"
    prompt: "What is merchant name?"
    private: no
  - name: "password"
    prompt:  "Enter password"
    private: yes
    encrypt: "sha256_crypt"
    confirm: yes
    salt_size: 16
  tasks:
    - debug: var=s

    - name: update db
      shell : echo -n "insert into database (id, createdDate, updatedDate, username, sharedSecretHash) values (7, strftime('%s', 'now'), strftime('%s', 'now'), "{{ username }}", "{{ password }}");" | sqlite3 /tmp/test.db
```